# SharedViewModel's MutableLiveData Becomes Null In a Different Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to share MutableLiveData between a fragment and an activity. However, even though the MutableLiveData is not null in the Fragment, it comes out as null in the Activity. Is there something wrong with my implementation?

**SharedViewModel:**

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val cartItemsLiveData = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<CartItem>>()
    var subtotal = MutableLiveData<Float>()
    var total = MutableLiveData<Float>()
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

//code

fun setData() {
    sharedViewModel.subtotal.value = 100.0f
    //I've verified that the value gets set and is not null
}
```

**Activity:**

```
val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

//code

fun setViews() {
    //the value here comes out as null
    tvSubtotal.text = sharedViewModel.subtotal.value.toString()
}
```

Is there anything wrong with the way SharedViewModel is declared considering it's a fragment and an activity? Any support/suggestions are welcome. Thank you!

Comment: In activity we don't have `by activityViewModels()`, it's just `by viewModels()`. Also, are you sure, `setData` function is called before `setViews`?

Comment: Just checked and yep, it gets called. I tried `viewModels` as well, no luck. Thanks Arpit! @ArpitShukla

Comment: Your question's title says "In a Different Activity" - ViewModels are tied to a specific instance of an activity; they aren't shared across all activities in your app. Are you trying to read the ViewModel in the same activity that your fragment is hosted in or in a different activity entirely?

Comment: I see. Fragment is hosted in a different activity, and I'm trying read from another. Is there a way to share LiveData with other activities? I did this to keep one instance of the data and allow different views to read from it. Open to hearing suggestions! Thank you! :) @ianhanniballake

Comment: @PJDP i don't think it's possible to share `LiveData` with other activities ,if possible you should change your apps to single activity architecture and create `SharedViewModels` with `NavGraph` as it's host by using `by navGraphViewModels()` will solve your problem.
ref : https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic

Comment: That's true! I'm going to update to a single activity architecture. Thanks for your suggestion @MuhammadRio